# Logic behind p / primes[i] >= primes[i] while finding prime numbers using array

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop

So I am a beginner in C and while I have experience in python I can't wrap my brain around a simple problem.

Finding prime numbers in Python was a easier task if I remember but I am facing difficulties while doing the same in C.

So from the tutorials I've been following this is code to find the prime numbers between 3 and 100 using arrays:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int p;
    int i;

    int primes[50] = { 0 };
    int primeIndex = 2;

    bool isPrime;

    // hardcode prime numbers
    primes[0] = 2;
    primes[1] = 3;

    for (p = 5; p <= 100; p = p + 2)
    {
        isPrime = true;

        for (i = 1; isPrime && p / primes[i] >= primes[i]; ++i)
            if (p % primes[i] == 0)
                isPrime = false;

        if (isPrime == true)
        {
            primes[primeIndex] = p;
            ++primeIndex;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0;  i < primeIndex;  ++i)
         printf("%i  ", primes[i]);

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The first `for` loop in the above code was understandable but what happened after the second one is confusing me.

What is the logic behind the `p / primes[i] >= primes[i]` condition in the second for loop?

For example if I follow the loop taking `p = 5` and apply the condition it'll be `5 / primes[1] >= primes[1]`:

Since we know `primes[1] = 3` this will become `5 / 3 >= 3` which immediately becomes false.

Please explain what is happening after the first for loop

Edit: I have added the python code which I can do by myself. Why isn't it possible to do the same way in C:

```
lst = [2]
for i in range(3, 100):
     for j in range(2, i):
          if (i % j) == 0:
                break
     else:
          lst.append(i)

print(lst)
```

Comment: looks like a recurrence relation / dynamic programming example

Comment: This is checking whether `primes[i]` is bigger than the square root of `p`, without actually calculating the square root.

Comment: @user253751 And why are we doing that

Comment: @Xtense: Because you never need to check for divisibility by numbers above the square root; if it's divisible by a number above the square root, it is also divisible by a matching number below the square root that you'd have already tested. Proof left as an exercise.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Ok so I understood the condition of the inner ```for```loop but what happens inside it.What is ```p % primes[i] == 0``` doing?

Comment: @Xtense: You need to go through a proper C tutorial if you don't understand that one. It's a simple operator. We can't teach you all of C a question at a time.

Comment: @ShadowRanger What I am saying is,now taking p = 6,we see the inner loop condition has passed,so now we are checking whether 6 is divisible by any previous prime numbers in the array using the ```p % primes[i] == 0``` condition as we find,it is divisible by 3,hence the ```isPrime = False``` condtion.Am I right?

Comment: @Xtense: Yes, `% primes[i] == 0` means 6 is divisible by 3 (no remainder), hence `isPrime = False`.  Q: Are you completely clear?  If not, is it C syntax or the algorithm that you're unclear about?  PS: There are many possible algorithms; it's entirely possible that the Python solution you're familiar with uses a *different* one...

Comment: @Xtense `from the tutorials I've been following` Follow different tutorials. Seriously.

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks,I think I get it now.Actually I wondered why did we have to go through such a long process.I have added my python code for the same problem,which had a very simple algo: Check for each number in the range whether it is divisble by any no in the range (0,i) and if not append it to the list

Comment: @dxiv Oh,actually it was the most recommended one.Feel free to suggest me another one

Comment: @Xtense Then find a different recommender ;-) OK, maybe I was a bit harsh. But this was obviously meant to be cleverer than the brute force in your python code. But, for a quip, I don't see why it would use repeated checks and division in the `for` loop condition, rather than multiplication and a `break` once hit.

Answer (score 0):

The inner `for` loop tries all odd prime numbers found so far up to an including `sqrt(p)` without actually computing `sqrt(p)`. The loop stops as soon as it finds a prime number that evenly divides `p`. It might be more readable as:

```
    isPrime = true;
    for (i = 1; p / primes[i] >= primes[i]; ++i) {
        if (p % primes[i] == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
```

In the case of `5`, to loop does not start because `5 < 3*3`, `5` is a prime number, same for `7`: no test is needed to determine its primality.

Your python code is more elegant thanks to the `else:` clause of the `for` statement that executes only if the loop exits normally. Yet the algorithm in the python version is much less efficient as you test all numbers, including even ones and all divisors up to `i`. For `100`, the difference is barely noticeable, but for much larger ranges, the added complexity will show. Also note that `lst` should be initialized as `lst = [2]` for the list of prime numbers to be correct, and you can remove the `if i > 1:` which is redundant.

Comment: and for ```9``` checking ```9 % 3 == 0``` is satisfied hence ```isPrime = False``` so we move on to the next number

Comment: And I think in my python code I am checking for all the numbers in the range ```(0, i)``` so there is no need for a predefined condition but in the C code,some numbers are automatically getting eliminated due to the prespecified conditions.Maybe its a matter of time complexity,C code does it faster whereas python one takes time as each number is tested in loops?